# Monotonic Interpolation in 2D

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I would like to use [scipy.interpolate.interp2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html) or [scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline) to interpolate a 2D image, but would like for the interpolation to be monotonic.

Is there an equivalent function that assures monotonicity or a way to force interp2d or RectBivariateSpline to return monotonic interpolations?

I believe I am looking for something similar to [PchipInterpolator](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator), but for 2D (or n-dimensional).

Comment: see example in this [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.pchip_interpolate.html)

Comment: thank you, but it seems like the "pchip interpolation" is not monotonic (judging from the plot in the example)

Comment: may be this what you are looking [for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56551114/fully-monotone-interpolation-in-python)

Comment: thank you again. It is similar to what I'm looking for, but I would like a solution for 2d

Answer (score 1):

The first question is: How do you define monotonicity in 2D (and in higher dimensions)? It seems to be not unique. I searched and found this paper: Piecewise polynomial monotonic interpolation of 2D gridded data (https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01059532/document). Maybe this helps.

The function RectBivariateSpline in scipy is wrapped around fitpack (as I remember, but maybe not). If that is the case, then it wouldn't be monotonic, it is b-spline-based.