# Creating an incremental smooth spline curve instead of non-uniform increments in python

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, spline

I am trying to smoothen my data using spline - which is basically cumulative percentile on the y-axis and a reference point they refer to on the x-axis. I get most part of it correct, however, the challenge I am facing is my y axis is increasing in a non linear way - as seen int he spline plot below- y-axis value keep increasing and decreasing, instead of just increasing.

I still want a smooth curve but want y-axis to increase with the x-axis - i.e. each subsequent y-axis point should be equal or a slight increment in value from the previous value, as opposed to increasing and the decreasing later.

Reproducible code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure 

percentile_block_df = pd.DataFrame({ 
'x' : [0.5,100.5,200.5,400.5,800.5,900.5,1000.5], 
'percentile' : [0.0001,0.01,0.065,0.85,0.99,0.9973,0.9999] 
})

figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=80) 
y = percentile_block_df.percentile 
x = percentile_block_df.x 

X_Y_Spline = make_interp_spline(x, y) 

# Returns evenly spaced numbers 
# over a specified interval. 
X_ = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 1000)
Y_ = X_Y_Spline(X_)

figure(figsize=(18, 6), dpi=80)
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1) # row 1, col 2 index 1
plt.plot(x, y,"ro")
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.title("Original")
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Percentile ')

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2) # index 2
plt.plot(x, y,"ro")
plt.plot(X_, Y_,"green")
plt.title("Spline Plot")
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Percentile ')

plt.show()
```

[image: See Chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is "monotonicity preserving interpolation". A quick search shows that [`scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator.html) does just that. Here is the result for your example when simply plugging in `from scipy.interpolate import PchipInterpolator` instead of `from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline`.

[image]

Whether or not that's appropriate depends of course on your specific requirements for the interpolation. I encourage you to research the other options which are out there.

Similar question:

- [Fully monotone interpolation in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56551114/fully-monotone-interpolation-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Code that eventually worked for me:

This [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_cubic_interpolation#:%7E:text=In%20the%20mathematical%20field%20of,not%20guaranteed%20by%20cubic%20interpolation.), explains the need for Monotone cubic interpolation

```
#this code allows "smoothening" of the data
B_spline_coeff1 = PchipInterpolator(x1, np.log(y1))
X1_Final = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 1000)
Y1_Final = np.exp(B_spline_coeff1(X1_Final))

#plot subplots
figure(figsize=(18, 6), dpi=80)
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1) # row 1, col 2 index 1
plt.plot(x, y,"ro")
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.title("Original")
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Percentile ')

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2) # index 2
plt.plot(x, y,"ro")
plt.plot(X1_Final, Y1_Final,"green")
plt.title("Spline Plot")
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Percentile ')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?